# Can we use add_row from tidyverse::tibble with across

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

Suppose I need to use `add_row` at last of a data set say `iris` like this!

```
iris %>% add_row( Species = "Total", Sepal.Length = sum(.$Sepal.Length)) %>% tail(3)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
151        876.5          NA           NA          NA     Total
```

My question is how can we use this method only ( I know other methods like `bind_rows` with `summarise` , `janitor`, `pivottabler`, `kable` etc.) to add a total of all numeric columns, without hardcoding their names.   Something `across` kinda thing.  Is this even possible?

**I am looking for future possible use cases of `add_row()` function which I haven't used till now so I am not interested in alternative methods**

**UPDATE** I just did it like this

```
iris %>% add_row(Species = "Total", iris[1:4] %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(.))))

149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8  virginica
151        876.5       458.6        563.7       179.9      Total
```

any better suggestions?

Comment: Regarding the update, it could be written like this: `iris %>% add_row(Species = "Total", summarise(., across(-Species, sum)))`

Comment: That's way better.  Thanks @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `adorn_totals`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   adorn_totals(col = 'Sepal.Length')
```

---

Or for multiple columns

```
iris %>% 
   select(Species, everything()) %>% 
   adorn_totals() %>% 
   select(names(iris))
```

---

Or for multiple columns

```
iris %>% 
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>% 
   add_row(iris, Species = 'Total', .)
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal what is your expected behavior

Comment: @AnilGoyal Because in your code you are just doing the sum of a specific column